# Unexplained assertion failure in my C++ snippet

Tags: c++, memory-corruption

The following is a snippet I was able to distill from a much larger code base to hopefully illustrate some sort of memory corruption that at the moment I am unable to see. This is using g++ 6.3.0 on Ubuntu 17.04, though I see the same problem on gcc 7.0.1 and clang 4.0.0.

```
#include <array>                                                                                                                                                                                                
#include <assert.h>                                                                                                                                                                                             

using Msg = std::array<char,sizeof(std::string)*2> ;                                                                                                                                                            

class Str {                                                                                                                                                                                                     
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   explicit Str (std::string &&v) : v (std::move(v)) {}                                                                                                                                                         
   std::string v;                                                                                                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                                                                                                              

void f(Msg &tmsg)                                                                                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   Msg m;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   new (&m) Str ("hello");                                                                                                                                                                                      
   tmsg = m;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                               

int main( int , char* [] )                                                                                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   Msg tmsg;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   f(tmsg);                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   auto ptr = (Str*) &tmsg;                                                                                                                                                                                     
   assert(ptr->v == "hello");    // This fails                                                                                                                                                                               
   return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

When I try to run this I get:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -g -std=c++11 && ./a.out
a.out: main.cpp:24: int main(int, char**): Assertion `ptr->v == "hello"' failed.
Aborted
```

Any ideas? I have been staring at this for hours now and I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: `new (&m) Str ("hello"); ` results in a dangling reference after `f()` returned. And why are you trying to use _placement new_ at all there?

Comment: This code is a simplification. The real code is trying to package more or less arbitrary types into an event queue. The consumer of this queue recovers the type and cleans up when done.

Comment: Do not over-simplify your code examples here. You won't get really useful answers as a result.

Comment: `using Msg = std::array<char,sizeof(std::string)*2> ;`  this is a bad start

Comment: @user0042 it does not result in a dangling reference. There is not even any reference here .

Comment: M M,  bad start? What do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is not legal according to the C++ standard. There are multiple problems:

1. Alignment. You don't make sure your storage for a `Str` is aligned to the same boundary as `std::string`, so your code has undefined behavior no diagnostic required. It's simpler to use `std::aligned_storage_t` than `std::array` like you did.
2. You are trying to copy a `std::string` around by copying the underlying bytes around. That is not legal and the standard does not give you license to do that. It violates the basic lifetime requirements of nontrivial class types in C++, and violates strict aliasing rules in this situation.

In this function, the bad thing is happening

```
void f(Msg &tmsg)                                                                                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   Msg m;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   new (&m) Str ("hello");                                                                                                                                                                                      
   tmsg = m;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

when `tmsg = m` happens. That is when the underlying bytes are getting copies, but that is not how you can safely copy an object. If it is nontrivial, like std::string, and owns a resource like a heap-allocated buffer, the copy constructor needs to get called or the class cannot enforce its guarantees. (That line itself does not cause undefined behavior, but when you try to reinterpret tmsg bytes as a valid Str, that is UB.)

Note also that because you used placement new, and you never called the dtor anywhere, you are leaking the object that you new'ed. It doesn't matter that the buffer you stored it in lives on the stack, the buffer doesn't have responsibility to call the dtor, you do.

Also the optimizer is permitted to assume that you won't do attempt to copy nontrivial objects like this. The optimizer may assume that `tmsg` does not contain a valid `Str` object since a `Str` object constructor is never called there.

You could change this code to

```
void f(Msg &tmsg)                                                                                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   new (&tmsg) Str ("hello");                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

and fixed the alignment issue, and then I think it has well-defined behavior, at least I don't see other problems (other than leak).

It is okay to allocate objects in a buffer of storage but you must be very careful. I recommend you heed the advice of the good old ISO C++ FAQ:

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new

> ADVICE: Don’t use this “placement new” syntax unless you have to. Use it only when you really care that an object is placed at a particular location in memory.
>
> ...
>    (if you don’t know what “alignment” means, please don’t use the placement new syntax). You have been warned.

---

Edit: Based on comment above:

> The real code is trying to package more or less arbitrary types into an event queue. The consumer of this queue recovers the type and cleans up when done.

What I would suggest you do is use a `variant`, like `boost::variant` or `std::variant`. This is a type-safe union that will manage the details of placement new within the buffer, safely copying and moving things, calling dtors etc. You could have a queue which is `std::vector<variant<....>>` or similar, and you would not then have this genre of low-level problems.

Another way to understand what the issue is: if `f` is changed like so, and the alignment issue is fixed, you can do this:

```
void f(Msg &tmsg)                                                                                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   Msg m;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   new (&m) Str ("hello");                                                                                                                                                                                      
   new (&tmsg) Str(*reinterpret_cast<Str*>(&m));
}
```

Because you are calling the copy ctor using placement new syntax, the new `Str` properly begins its lifetime in the buffer `tmsg` and it makes a copy of the one in `m`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, I will try to correct the aligment issue. In the real code, from which this snipet was extracted, the destructor is called on the recovered pointer. I understand that the string cannot be memcopied normally, but I believed this would be OK precisely because no string destructor was called on m, so whatever buffers were allocated by the string constructor would still be valid and in the same location, so tmsg would be fine. Can you elaborate on why this wouldn't be the case?

Comment: So, using g++ 6.3 on ubuntu 17, your `std::string` is going to have the small string optimization -- there isn't any buffer on the heap here, the chars will be internal and live in the `Str`. It's not about like, the internals getting confused about who owns a buffer. If you rewrote the code to use placement new `std::string` copy ctor instead, I bet that the underlying bytes of the two strings would be exactly the same. The reason this code is broken is that the compiler writers get to assume that you don't write code like this, and make optimizations based on that assumption, and they do.

Comment: Chris, this code is extremly performance sensitive and when I briefly looked at variant (boot or std) I found them too complicated to possibly be any fast. The queue class I am using does not offer inplace construction of messages, hence the memcopy from m to msg (which mimicks what that queue will do).

Comment: So, u might want to roll your own variant-like class. If theres no exceptions and u dont need it to be general, it can be very simple, and all of it is easily inlined by the optimizer, no rtti or virtual dispatch. If the queue doesnt support inplace construction and its performance critical u might want to find a replacement queue. There shouldnt be any performance loss incurred by choosing a variant, it shd be very similar to performance of hand-rolled placement new in buffers, tagged union, etc. I can post example code / links later